# reload state on angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My question is can to change the menu without reload the data. Now, when click for example on Dashboard link, the state should reload and all data of page shiuld be reloaded including its controller.

I am using UI router for tabs of a main menu.

Here's my code:

My **dashboardApplication.js** file is:

```
var dashboard = angular.module('dashboard', ['ui.router']);

dashboard.config(["$stateProvider", function ($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('app.dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'app/modules/dashboard/views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Home'
        }
});

$stateProvider.state('app.general', {
    url: '/general',
    reloadOnSearch: false,
    templateUrl: 'app/modules/dashboard/views/general.html',
    controller: 'GeneralController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'General'
    }
});

$stateProvider.state('app.message', {
    url: '/message',
    templateUrl: 'app/modules/dashboard/views/message.html',
    controller: 'MessageController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'message'
    }
});

}]);
```

My **app.js** file is:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'dashboard']);

    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                url: '/app',
                abstract: true,
                reloadOnSearch: false,
                templateUrl: 'app/common/app.html',
                controller: 'appCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                data: {
                    pageTitle: 'dashboard'
                }
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/general');

    }]);    

    app.config(function ($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    }).run(function ($location) {
        $location.path('/');
    });
```

My **appCtrl.js** file is:

```
    app.controller("appCtrl", ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$location', 'Flash', 'appSettings', '$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', '$http',
        function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, $location, Flash, appSettings, $translate, $translatePartialLoader, $http) {

        vm.menuItems = [
                    {
                        title: "Dashboard",
                        icon: "map-o",
                        state: "dashboard",
                        visible: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Structure",
                        icon: "gears",
                        state: "structure",
                        visible: appSettings.SHOW_STRUCTURE
                    },
                    {
                        title: "General",
                        icon: "clone",
                        state: "general",
                        visible: appSettings.OBJ_READ
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Message",
                        icon: "envelope-o",
                        state: "message",
                        visible: appSettings.ADM_MSG
                    }
                ];

    }]);
```

And parts of **index** page is:

```
        <ul class="sidebar-menu" >
            <li class="treeview" ui-sref-active="active" ng-click="vm.sideBar();" data-ng-repeat="menu in vm.menuItems">
                <a ui-sref="app.{{menu.state}}" ng-hide="{{menu.visible}}" >
                    <i class="fa fa-{{menu.icon}}"></i> <span>{{menu.title}}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can add `ui-sref-opts="{ reload: true }"` to `<a ui-sref="app.{{menu.state}}" ng-hide="{{menu.visible}}" >` if you want to force reloading the state

Comment: I made a change but it does not work!

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work, can you clarify it please?

Comment: For exemple on Dashboard menu i have a text box. Fill any value in that. 
Now again click on Dashboard the state reload and all data of page should be reloaded including its controller.
I want to keep this data when I come back from another menu

Comment: Oh, well in that case you need to save the value _somewhere_. You can save it on the server side, and then fetch the data, or on the client side using localStorage/sessionStorage (for example) using https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage Read hot to use it and I think this is what you're looking for